# The general solution of $x\dfrac{dy}{dx} = y$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How to find the general solution to this differential equation?

Since $x$ and $y$ can be zero, I think I need to consider four separate cases: $(x=0,y=0)$, $(x\neq 0,y=0)$, and so on.

But I don't know how to proceed: I found when $x=0$, $y=0$, what does this mean??

If I divide both side by $xy$, then $|y| = C|x|$, where both $x$ and $y$ are non zero values. But how to take care of the situation when either of $x$ or $y$ is zero?

Comment: Just substitute $x = 0$ into the original differential equation. You will find that these cases are covered by $C = 0$.

Comment: @TobyMak You mean the original equation? 0 dy/dx = 0?

Comment: what do you mean by four separate cases? if one of $x$ or $y$ is equal to zero then there is no solution. @TFR

Comment: @TFR Yes, that's what I mean. Actually for $x = 0$, $dy/dx$ does not exist, but for $y = 0$ it certainly does.

Comment: The equation is false when $x = 0$ and $y\neq 0,$ so no need to solve it then. If $y=0$ then either $x = 0$ or $\frac{dy}{dx} =0,$ which I think covers that case.

Comment: @Yassir But isn't y = 0 a solution?

Comment: $$x\frac{dy}{dx}=y\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x}$$ $$\frac{1}{y}dy=\frac{1}{x}dx$$ if $x$ or $y$ is zero then how can you solve this @TFR

Comment: This only is valid given that $x \ne 0$ and $y \ne 0$. You're introducing an additional restriction that does not happen when looking at the original.

Comment: Or more simply, take $x = 0$. If we divide by $x$ on both sides, $1 = 0$ given that $x \ne 0$ to avoid division by $0$. From $1 = 0$ alone we cannot conclude there are no solutions, so we have to take into account $x = 0$ as well.

Comment: @DavidK "If y=0 then either x=0 or dy/dx=0, which I think covers that case". What really confuses me is when y = 0 and x = 0.  Isn't that a point? What is the derivative?

Comment: @TobyMak How do you divide by x on both sides when you take x = 0?

Comment: $\frac{x}{x} = \frac{0}{x} \Rightarrow 1 = 0$.

Comment: Considering that the possible trajectories converge into the point $(0,0)$ from all directions I suppose a reasonable assumption is the derivative is not defined there.

Comment: You can use the integrating factor method to solve a first order ODE like this. The integrating factor turns out to be $e^{ln(x)} = x$ in this case. This leads us to the solutions $x=0$ (which implies $y=0$) or $xy=C$ for some constant $C$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor#Solving_first_order_linear_ordinary_differential_equations

Answer (score 1):

So the case $x=0$ just implies that $y(0)=0$. This is more of an additional boundary condition that has to taken into account.

The case $y=0$ is more interesting because it provides an additional solution (namely $y\equiv0$). Well it is not really an additional solution because it can be also achieved by generalising the constant $C=e^{C^*}$ from your computation.

Now the question is how much regularity you impose on your solution. If you expect your solution to be $C^1$ your only option is $y(x)=Cx$ for $C\in\mathbb{R}$. If you relax your assumptions on the regularity to e.g. lipschitz you can use the interesting point $y=0$ to glue together different branches of your solution and still fulfill the ODE in a pointwise sense.
$$
y(x)=\begin{cases}C_1x&x<0\\C_2x&x\geq0\end{cases}
$$
for $C_1,C_2\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

$x=0$ implies $y=0$, and $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ is free.

$y=0$ implies either $x=0$ (already seen), or $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=0$, which is perforce true, and $x$ is free. Hence $y=0$ is a solution.

Now we can assume $x\ne0,y\ne0$ and write

$$\frac{dy}y=\frac{dx}x.$$

Taking the antiderivative of both members,

$$\log|y|+c_y=\log|x|+c_x$$ where $c_x,c_y$ are two arbitrary constant, which can be combined in one.

Then taking the antilogarithm,

$$|y|=c|x|,$$ or $$y=\pm c|x|$$ which indeed satisfies the original equation, provided we change the sign at $x=0$ to ensure continuity.

Finally, $$y=cx$$ with no restrictions on $x,y,c$.

Comment: I know when we assume x and y both are unequal to zero,  we get y = cx or y =  c|x| where x,y,c are both non-zero reals (according a previous post asked by me). But I don't see how this combine with y = 0 to give y = cx for all values or x,y,and c. Can you please elaborate on this more?

Answer (score 0):

> But I don't know how to proceed: I found when $x=0$, $y=0$, what does this mean??

When you put $x=0$ in your ODE of form $by'(x)+ay(x)=c$ you are not looking for a solution of ODE rather you look for a condition like $ay(0)+by'(0)=c$. In your case, it gives $y(0)=0$.

Now for the reverse case of plugging $y=0$, you can observe that ODE gives $0=0$ which shows that $y(x)=0$ is a solution (*trivial*) satisfying the condition $y(0)=0$.

> How to find the general solution to this differential equation?

The general solution can be simply found as follows:

$xy'-y=0\implies \frac{xy'-y}{x^2}=0, x\ne 0$
$\implies d(y/x)=c
\implies y=cx, c\in\mathbb R$

is the general solution satisfying $y(0)=0$